# How is the "Consider including" feature in Gmail implemented?

Tags: algorithm, database-design

I would like to do something similar to gmail's *"consider including"* suggestions on my blog, but with tags.

I was thinking of storing tags sets like this :
[image: three tables]

and I thought of the following algorithm :

```
//a blog post is published
//it has the tags "A", "B" & "C" :
if the tag set "A,B,C" doesn't exist
   create it
else
   add 1 to "number of times used"
```

and, to suggest tags :

```
//a blog post is being written.
//the author includes the tags "A" and "C"
//which tags should I suggest ?
find all the tags sets that contain "A" and "C"
  among them, find the one with the highest "number of times used"
    suggest the tags of the set not already picked (A & C)
```

Is there a better/smarter way of accomplishing this task ? What about the database model ? Can I optimize it so that searches like *"sets that contain A & C"* won't be too slow ?

Comment: “Suggesting Friends Using the Implicit Social Graph” http://research.google.com/pubs/pub36371.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Search model** issues:

Your model seems a bit too simplified to me, since very frequent tags are most likely to always be the suggested ones, even if there are tags more related to the pair A,C.

You probably should concider the [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%2aidf) model, which gives a boost to rare terms, if they are also connected to the "query" [in here the query is `A and B`], since if a rare term is commonly used with `A and B` - it is probably very much related to them.

The idea is simple: If a tag is frequently used with `A and B` - give it a boost. [tf]

Also, if a term is rare [number of total uses of this tag] - give it a boost [idf]

The "score" for each tag will be the combined tf-idf score

**Performance issues:**

You might also concider for this task creating an [inverted index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index) - to speed up searches.

If you are using java, [apache lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) is a mature library that can help you with it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is typical data association mining and recommendation problem. You can try google Apriori algorithm for data mining and make a TOP N recommendation.

Your solution will work but not comprehensive in my option. such as set "A,B" and set "A,B,C" are not independent sets.